# Unexpected Opearator in for loop in makefile

Tags: for-loop, makefile

```
for dir in " b/. c/. obj/. src/. "; do \
        if [ $dir != "src/." ] && [ $dir != "obj/." ]; then \
            make -C $dir; \
        fi; \
    done
```

Here the error coming is `/bin/sh: 2: [: b/.: unexpected operator` why am I getting this error. b/. is the sub directory of the directory in which makefile is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for dir in b/. c/. obj/. src/.; do \
    if [ "$$dir" != "src/." ] && [ "$$dir" != "obj/." ]; then \
        make -C $$dir; \
    fi; \
done
```

Changes:

- Escape `$dir` as `$$dir` so `make` doesnt think you're using the `$d` variable
- Put quotes around `$$dir`
- Remove quotes from `for` arguments, so they don't get interpreted as a single one.
- added some spaces

Comment: Thanx.i got it correct.But one question while substituting macros we use a single $ but in using the variable dir in for loop and while substituting its value we use $$.Why??

Comment: That's because a single `$` gets interpreted as a Make variable, not a shell variable.

Comment: if i Use $(dir) instead of $$dir the is it correct??

Comment: Nope, `$(dir)` would still mean "the `dir` variable in this Makefile". `$$` tells `make` to output a literal `$`, and the shell interprets it as you intended

Comment: THANKX :) It helped a LOT in executing a shell commands in makefile